# Parent package name repeated in Android Studio project view

Tags: android-studio

After refactoring the name of a base package, Android Studio now displays the full package name for all subpackages of the refactored package in the Project / Android treeview.  The directory names and package declarations in the Java files are correct, so this seems to be related to an .idea file.

This is what I'm seeing  (The blurred package name is the same in all instances):
[image]

Any suggestions?  I've noticed a couple of times that the issue temporarily corrects itself while Android Studio performs a background process.

Comment: Can you try checking and unchecking the Flatten Package option in the gearwheel menu?

Comment: @VadimCaen  Good suggestion!  Unfortunately, the problem persists.

Comment: Does the same problem happens in project view? I am trying to understand if it is a bug on IJ side, AS side or your side.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to disable flat hierarchy in Project pane.

1) Click Show Options menu button.
2) Uncheck Flatten Packages.
3) Optional: Uncheck Compact Empty Middle Package

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnaLA.png]